# Count interest in common in two table

Tags: sql

I made a huge SQL line for a school project of meeting website and i have a little problem for a query to find the better person with multiple criteria (Localisation, sexual orientation and center of interest), the only missing in my query is the interest.

i have a little problem for having the number of interest in common for one user. My table are like this

```
Users
+---+----------+
|ID |   USER   | ...
+---+----------+
|1  |User1     | ...
+---+----------+
|2  |User2     | ...
+---+----------+
|3  |User3     | ...
+---+----------+

usersInterest :
+---+-------------+-------------+
|ID |   id_user   | id_interest |
+---+-------------+-------------+
|1  |1            | 1           |
+---+-------------+-------------+
|2  |1            | 2           |
+---+-------------+-------------+
|3  |2            | 1           |
+---+-------------+-------------+
|4  |2            | 3           |
+---+-------------+-------------+
|5  |3            | 4           |
+---+-------------+-------------+
|6  |3            | 5           |
+---+-------------+-------------+
```

I want a column with the interest in commun with the user 1. They share the id 1 with users 2 and have nothing in common with users 3.
This will giving this with user1 by example :

```
+---+----------+----------------+
|ID |   USER   | COMMON_INTEREST|
+---+----------+----------------+
|2  |User2     |1               | << Have idinterest 1 in common
+---+----------+----------------+
|3  |User3     |0               |
+---+----------+----------------+
```

I dont find a working solution on the internet who working.

Comment: Have you tried anything?   Where are you in your SQL learning?   Have you learned about outer joins yet?   Why do you have ID 2 on the second row of your desired output?   What does the 2 represent?

Comment: could you provide a sample of what the output for a given situation should be? Yours isn't complex enough, e.g. what happens if the have multiple common interests, is there the count or are there multiple results one for each interest?

Comment: i want just the count of interest in common with a particular user, i edit a little my question.

The 2, just the id of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for your requirement:

```
    SELECT T1.ID,T1.USER,T2.COMMON_INTEREST FROM table_name1 T1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, COUNT(id_interest) as COMMON_INTEREST
        FROM table_name2  GROUP BY ID) T2
        ON (T1.ID = T2.ID);
```

Joining first table with the second using ID column. Generating the count of id_interest by grouping on basis of ID and selecting required column in the select clause.

Comment: Updated the query

Comment: i noticed, deleted my comment

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it for the interest one, this query work with this query :

```
select ui.id_users, COUNT(up.id_interest) from users_usersInterest ui left join (SELECT id_interest FROM `users_usersInterest` WHERE id_users = 6) up on up.id_interest = ui.id_interest group by ui.id_users
```